# PHP Inside link titles

Tags: php, html

Not exactly sure how to look this up elsewhere.. so I posted it here

```
  echo '<a href="http://www.roblox.com/Groups/group.aspx?gid='. $d['GroupId'].'" title="'.$smb.'"><font color="Black">'. $d['GroupName'].'</a></font>';
```

The links and all of that work correctly, but I was planning on having the title get your group rank (it gets the rank) yet I cannot put it inside the title.

Forgive me, I'm a bit rusty on PHP been working on Lua alot more than PHP lately.

Comment: `var_dump($smb)` Does it contain anything? Also it's better to close first `font` and then `a`, not vice-versa.

Comment: Actually better not to use font at all. Css is the way :)

Comment: I get bool(false).. which isnt suppost to be what I'm getting

Comment: Does $smb contain characters that could break the a element?

Comment: I found the problem.. but I don't believe its fixable, the API that gets the primary group - requires a player username, however the API that gets the player rank requires a id

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="http://www.roblox.com/Groups/group.aspx?gid='. $d['GroupId'].'" title="'.$smb.'"><font color="Black">'. $d['GroupName']." - ".$d['GroupRank'].'</a></font>';
```

Comment: $d is decoded JSON, not rank area   $url2 = 'http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=GetGroupRole&playerid='.$rbxid.'&groupid='. $d['GroupId'].'';
$data2 = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options2 = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context2  = stream_context_create($options2);
$smb = file_get_contents($url2, false, $context2);